# Image on Orchard CMS Menu items

Tags: orchardcms

How to have images to my navigation items in orchard ? In my orchard application I had added 6 navigation items. How to add images to all items there?

Comment: Why -1 to this question ? Can I know ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a follow-up on @Xceno's answer, this is what I did when I wanted this functionality:

1. Add a textfield to the MenuPart in content definition, called 'Icon'
2. Override 'MenuItemLink.cshtml', with the following content (I used font awesome for icons, change the 'fa' stuff for whatever you use):

---

```
@{
    var icon = Model.Content.ContentItem.MenuPart.Icon.Value;
}

<a href="@Model.Href">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(icon)) {
        <i class="fa fa-@icon"></i> 
    }
    <span class="nav-label">@Model.Text</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar question some time ago:
[Orchard CMS: Modifying a menu item alternate and iterating over the items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510111/orchard-cms-modifying-a-menu-item-alternate-and-iterating-over-the-items)

You could for example write an alternate for the MenuItemLink and add your images there.

From the other answer:

**MenuItemLink.cshtml**

```
<a href="@Model.Href" class="my-super-cool-custom-link">
    <img src="wherever/img.jpg" />@Model.Text
</a>
```